# Git push changes always force for pull

Tags: git

We are using git in our organization.
Now whenever we try to push the code in origin/development branch from our local development branch. Git always force us to take a pull before pushing the changes.

Is it possible to push the change without git pull ?

We tried out to create new branch from development branch. lets say dev_mybranch. 
and pushed the branch to origin. So it is possible to merge origin/dev_mybranch to origin/dev branch ? In this way we may avoid to take pull each time. Can anyone help me out in this.

Because each time we take a pull. It takes a lot of time to setup the workspace again.

Answer (score -1):

`git push -f <repository> <branch>`
This should force push command.

Comment: thanks @Jakub Chlebowicz I will try that, Just have one more query, In case of merge conflict does my origin/branch will be impacted with this ?

Comment: Sure. -f "overwrites". In order to do a "merge"... well, that's what the pull does. Basically what git is telling you when you try to push and it tells you that you should pull before is that there are changes on the remote branch that you don't have on your local branch. So you need to "merge"...  or rebase your branch... it really depends on what you like/need.